How to lock/disable keyboard and mouse untill a set datetime?
How to disable keyboard/mouse?
And to re-enable them at a chosen datetime, e.g. 2024.11.19 06:00. Or after a set amount of time, e.g. 8 Hours.

Many input devices use USB, even if they’re technically internal devices. One method would be to have a script disable power to those specific USB devices at a set time and re-enable at a set time, but this may have numerous unintended requests. It would also not survive a hard reboot
